# Change the image link dynamically in responsive mode

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

how to change the images link dynamically in responsive mode.
i am working on the wordpress and showing the thumbnails having fixed size **280*200** but in the resolution between **480px to 600px** i am wanted to change the thumbnail size to medium(which i have set to **480*200**) how i can achieve this?
any script to  detect the device resolution and change the img src automatically to medium size thumbnails???
like this

**(in desktop versions)**

```
<img class="attachment-thumb-small wp-post-image" src="280x200.jpg">
```

**(in mobile versions)**

`<img  class="attachment-thumb-medium wp-post-image" src="480x200.jpg">`

Answer (score 3):

try adding media query to your css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    .attachment-thumb-medium, .wp-post-image{
width: 480px;
height: 200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will simply stretch the image. Someone is going to have a very long face.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

A. You can set images in CSS as background for empty `<div>` elements. Then you can use a media query in CSS to change the image source.

```
.thumbnail {background-image:url("280x200.png")};
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .thumbnail {background-image:url("480x200.png")};
}
```

B. You can detect the screen size using JavaScript, and then change the image tags in your PHP code - or using JavaScript again. It's more work, though. See [PHP - Detect the display resolution](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1251-php-detect-the-display-resolution) for details.

Comment: any method to chage src  link in in img tag?